# Ubuntu Application Running Issues

Tags: software-installation

I have Ubuntu Studio 16.10 on my PC.

For some reason, when I go to open a newly downloaded program, I cannot run the .exe file. I click on the file and it simply opens it up to show the components inside. I am unable to run it.

How do I do I run it?!

Thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu linux execute files have the extension `.deb`, to use `.exe` on Ubuntu please use `wine`

Answer (score 0):

Linux cannot run .exe files, as these are Windows specific. There should be a separate linux download for most software. If the program in question is Windows-only, you might want to look at [wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: AH! Of course! What are the execution files on Linux called?